# What is the best Virtual Reality headset for research purposes

Tags: headset, vr-headset

I am currently doing my Msc. research paper on an area which involves developing a specialized virtual reality app thus requiring a good VR headset, so whats the best on-budget recommended headset that i can begin with

**Edited**

what i am specifically looking into is a headset which is compatible, comfortable & on-budget(under 300$) enough to support a realistically simulated VR content developed by unity3D through which a user can navigate inside the simulation and interact with things.

sorry for the simplistic nature of my question, am new to VR content creation and peripherals involved in the process.

Comment: There is not enough detail here. What is "on-budget"? Conceivably you could do your research on something as cheap as [Google Cardboard](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/), but you didn't provide any information so we don't know for sure. What headsets have you looked at? Why would (or wouldn't) they work?

Comment: I've placed this on hold until you can provide more details.

Comment: @Andy, i have edited my question above and added some more clarifications.

Comment: How much is "on-budget enough" to support X? Without clear technical specs of your desired headset, there is still too much room for interpretation. It's best if you can provide a quantitative amount (e.g. under $500).

Comment: @BennettYeo, headsets under 300$